# Django cannot connect to running postgres docker container

Tags: django, linux, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am surprised that I cannot get this to work, as I have run a django applications with a postgres DB in docker containers multiple times, however, this time on my Linux machine the django application cannot connect to the postgres docker container, whereas on my Mac the setup works without a problem.

I am getting the standard error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Host is unreachable
> Is the server running on host "postgresdb" (172.27.0.2) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The postgres container is running and should be reachable. I check the IP address of the docker container and it seems correct. My docker-compose file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: data-management
    restart: always
    build: ./
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - 'postgresdb'
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/local/share/src/app
    env_file:
      - .dev.env

  postgresdb:
    container_name: be-postgres
    restart: always
    image: postgres:13.4-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .dev.env

volumes:
  postgres-db:
```

The configurations are stored in an environment file, which is used in both containers to avoid any mismatches.

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=devpassword123
POSTGRES_USER=devuser
POSTGRES_SERVICE=postgresdb
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=data_management
```

The django DB settings are as standard as they could be:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ['POSTGRES_SERVICE'],
        'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'],
        'PORT': os.environ['POSTGRES_PORT'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
    }
}
```

I am out of ideas as what could be causing this as this happens only on my Fedora machine and there are no issues when running on my Mac. I have already had SELinux problems with some docker volumes in the past, however, after googling I could not find any suggestions that SELinux could be the culprit again.

Comment: Anything in the Postgres container logs to suggest it isn't running properly?

Comment: Firewall blocking port? Can you do `psql -d <db_name> -p 5432 -h 172.27.0.2 -U <some_user>`? What is `listen_addresses` set to in `postgresql.conf`? Add answers as update to  question.

Comment: Sadly, there are no problems in the postgres logs. @AdrianKlaver when running the command in the postgres container, I can successfully connect to the database

Comment: That pretty much goes without saying. What you need to do is try connecting from outside the container as that is where the issue is. When you do add the complete command you use and result to your question.  Also please answer the other questions I asked as updates to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there are also no problems connecting to the database from outside the container. Sorry, I did not see the edited version - I haven't touched the configurations and the `listen_addresses` seems to be `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: If you have `psql` in your app container, try the command `PGPASSWORD=devpassword123 psql -h postgresdb -U devuser data_management`

Comment: Thanks everyone for adding comments! The problem was indeed in the firewall as @AdrianKlaver mentioned. Fedora changed from `iptables` to `nftables` and this broke the internal container communication. Changing it to `iptables` solved the problem, however, I am not sure if this solution is the best.